# Set size of JTextField with BoyLayout Manager. Java

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, boxlayout

I have seen this question been answered. but not for BoxLayout.
I have created a schedule app in Java and because I want to display every hour under each other, I have chosen BoxLayout. When every hour is displayed, everything looks perfect. However, before my method is called by clicking a button, the JTextField just takes up the whole screen (with the button). How do I make that different?

Main class:

```
public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setResizable(true);
                
    GamePanel gamepanel = new GamePanel();
    
    window.add(gamepanel);
    
    window.pack();
            
    window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    window.setVisible(true)
    
    }
}
```

GamePanel Class:

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    
    //Screen Settings
    final int originalTileSize = 16;
    final int scale = 3;
    final int tileSize = originalTileSize * scale;
    final int maxScreenCol = 16;
    final int maxScreenRow = 12;
    final int screenWidth = tileSize * maxScreenCol;
    final int screenHeight = tileSize * maxScreenRow;
    
    //Initialize the things that are displayed
    JButton knopf;
    JTextField field;
    Tage days; 
    String textInhalt;
    static JLabel displayIsSchool;
    static JLabel stunden;
    static JLabel stunden1;
    static JLabel stunden2;
    static JLabel stunden3;
    static JLabel stunden4;
    static JLabel stunden5;
    static JLabel stunden6;
    static JLabel stunden7;
    static JLabel stunden8;
    
        //Panel constructor
        public GamePanel(){
            
            super();
            this.setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
            
            //JFrame stats
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(screenWidth, screenHeight));
            this.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
            this.setDoubleBuffered(true);
            this.setFocusable(true);
            
            //Initialize Text field 
            field = new JTextField();
            field.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD,30));
            field.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (100, 50));
            
            //Initialize Button 
            knopf = new JButton("klick");
            knopf.addActionListener(this);
            knopf.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (100, 35));
            
            //Initialize isSchool
            displayIsSchool = new JLabel("");
            displayIsSchool.setForeground(Color.white);
            displayIsSchool.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD,30));
        
            //Initialize stunden
            stunden = new JLabel("");
            stunden.setForeground(Color.white);
            stunden.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD,30));
            
            stunden1 = new JLabel("");
            stunden1.setForeground(Color.white);
            stunden1.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD,30));
        
            stunden2 = new JLabel("");
            stunden2.setForeground(Color.white);
            stunden2.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD,30));
        
            stunden3 = new JLabel("");
            stunden3.setForeground(Color.white);
            stunden3.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD,30));
        
            stunden4 = new JLabel("");
            stunden4.setForeground(Color.white);
            stunden4.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD,30));
        
            stunden5 = new JLabel("");
            stunden5.setForeground(Color.white);
            stunden5.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD,30));
        
            stunden6 = new JLabel("");
            stunden6.setForeground(Color.white);
            stunden6.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD,30));
        
            stunden7 = new JLabel("");
            stunden7.setForeground(Color.white);
            stunden7.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD,30));
        
            stunden8 = new JLabel("");
            stunden8.setForeground(Color.white);
            stunden8.setFont(new Font("Serif",Font.BOLD,30));
        
            //Add everything to JFrame
            this.add(field);
            this.add(knopf);
            this.add(displayIsSchool);
            this.add(stunden);
            this.add(stunden1);
            this.add(stunden2);
            this.add(stunden3);
            this.add(stunden4);
            this.add(stunden5);
            this.add(stunden6);
            this.add(stunden7);
            this.add(stunden8);
        }
        
    //Call Method for set Day
    public void sayIf() {

        //Switch statement for user Input 
        switch(textInhalt) 
        {
                
            case "Montag":
                Montag.sagName();
                break;
            case "Dienstag":
                Dienstag.sagName();
                break;
            case "Mittwoch":
                Mittwoch.sagName();
                break;
            case "Donnerstag":
                Donnerstag.sagName();
                break;  
            case "Freitag":
                Freitag.sagName();      
                break;
            case "Samstag":
                Samstag.sagName();
                break;
            case "Sonntag":
                Sonntag.sagName();
                break;  
        }
    }   
    
        //schedule
        static String[] monHours = {"Bio", "Bio", "Mathe", "Mathe", "Chemie", "Chemie", "Frei", "Musik", "Musik"};
        static String[] dinHours = {"Deutsch", "Mathe", "Physik", "Physik", "Englisch", "Frei", "Französisch", "Frei", "Frei"};
        static String[] mitHours = {"Französisch", "Französisch", "Englisch", "Tutor", "Geschichte", "Geschichte", "Frei", "Sport", "Sport"};
        static String[] donHours = {"Englisch", "Englisch", "Deutsch", "Deutsch", "Informatik", "Informatik", "Frei", "Frei", "Frei"};
        static String[] freHours = {"PoWi", "PoWi", "Ethik", "Ethik", "Deutsch", "Frei", "Mathe", "Frei", "Frei"};
        static String[] samHours = {"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""};
        static String[] sonHours = {"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""};
        
        //create Day objects 
        static Tage Montag = new Tage(true, monHours, "Montag");
        static Tage Dienstag = new Tage(true, dinHours, "Dinestag")  ;
        static Tage Mittwoch = new Tage(true, mitHours, "Mittwoch")  ;
        static Tage Donnerstag = new Tage(true, donHours, "Donnerstag")  ;
        static Tage Freitag = new Tage(true, freHours, "Freitag")  ;
        static Tage Samstag = new Tage(false, samHours, "Samstag")  ;
        static Tage Sonntag = new Tage(false, sonHours, "Sonntag")  ;       
        
        
        //keyListener 
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(e.getSource()==knopf) {
    
                textInhalt = field.getText();
                sayIf();
            }
        }
}
```

Tag (Day) Class:

```
package basicsPack;

public class Tage{
    
    //Variables for constructor 
    boolean isSchool;
    String[] stunden;
    String name;
    
    //Tage constructor 
    public Tage(boolean isSchool, String[] stunden, String name) {
        
        this.isSchool = isSchool;  
        this.stunden = stunden;
        this.name = name;
        
    }
    
    //sagName method
    public void sagName() {
        
        //Display hours an rather I have school
        if(this.isSchool == true) {
        
            GamePanel.displayIsSchool.setText("Du hast am "+ name + " Schule ");
            GamePanel.stunden.setText(this.stunden[0]);
            GamePanel.stunden1.setText(this.stunden[1]);
            GamePanel.stunden2.setText(this.stunden[2]);
            GamePanel.stunden3.setText(this.stunden[3]);
            GamePanel.stunden4.setText(this.stunden[4]);
            GamePanel.stunden5.setText(this.stunden[5]);
            GamePanel.stunden6.setText(this.stunden[6]);
            GamePanel.stunden7.setText(this.stunden[7]);
            GamePanel.stunden8.setText(this.stunden[8]);
            
        }else {
            
            GamePanel.displayIsSchool.setText("Du hast am " + name + " keine Schule");
            GamePanel.stunden.setText("");
            GamePanel.stunden1.setText("");
            GamePanel.stunden2.setText("");
            GamePanel.stunden3.setText("");
            GamePanel.stunden4.setText("");
            GamePanel.stunden5.setText("");
            GamePanel.stunden6.setText("");
            GamePanel.stunden7.setText("");
            GamePanel.stunden8.setText("");
        }
    }
}
```

[image: This is what it looks like at the moment]

[image: This Is what I want it to look like]

Comment: 1) I wouldn't use BoxLayout for this. 2) Whenever I see lists of variables with increasing numbers at their ends, my mind yells out: "for the love of all things beautiful, use arrays or ArrayLists!" That code has so much ugly, dangerous and unnecessary repetition -- dangerous because one typo or seemingly trivial error and the whole house of cards comes crumbling down. Also, there is gross over-use of static modifier here. The only things that should be static in this program are the main method and any constants.

Comment: Also, I have no idea what sort of structure you're trying to create

Comment: As for what I'd use, again, I have no idea what sort of structure you're trying to build or how your program is supposed to look like. Please post an image or link to an image or something, anything. But BoxLayout isn't used for this sort of thing.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels. I want to have my text Box and my Button at the beginning. After any weekday is typed in, I also want to display If I have school on this day + every hour of this day under each other.

Comment: Picture, image, something please

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels. I'm here for critique. But don't just say: this is bad and this is bad. That doesn't help at all. If you want to comment on something that isn't included in my question, I probably don't even know *why* it is a problem. So, you'd have to be very detailed when it comes to stuff like that to not come of as unfriendly.

Comment: A picture or an image of your GUI, please

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels. You mean for displaying the school hours? I want to use JLabels for that. I just want to display text underneath each other. That works so far. But before the text is displayed, my text box just takes up all space.

Comment: Again, *show* what you're trying to create, don't just describe it. Draw it on paper and photograph the image or draw with some simple painting program.

Comment: If you don't want the JTextField to take up all the space, again, don't use a BoxLayout, or use it in a smart way (how, hard to say) but you're not showing what it supposed to look like. Please help a guy out here.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels. Okay, I will try to provide that. I didn't understand what you meant with a picture. mb

Comment: I'm not sure how I can be more clear about this. Your descriptions are very hard to follow.

Comment: Often, the JTextField and the button would often be in the same JPanel that is displayed in the PAGE_START location of a BorderLayout. You should probably be doing this. Here a BoxLayout could work fine.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels. I have edited my post. In the picture where I show what It should look like, I removed the BoxLayout Manager.

Comment: Thank you. BoxLayout could work fine as per my example below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So yes, put the JTextField and JButton in their own JPanel in a BoxLayout using JPanel, that is fine, and place that JPanel in the BorderLayout.PAGE_START position of a JPanel that uses BorderLayout with the rest of the GUI below it. For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Main2b {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            GamePanel2 mainPanel = new GamePanel2();

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(mainPanel);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class GamePanel2 extends JPanel {
    private JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
    private JButton knopf = new JButton("klick");
    
    public GamePanel2() {
        knopf.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_K);
        
        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(topPanel, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        topPanel.add(field);
        topPanel.add(knopf);
        
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(650, 400)));
        
    }
}
```

displays as

[image]

---

Other unrelated issues:

- Avoid static variables unless there is a distinct need to use them (that isn't the case here) such as constants of a class or fields that must be part of the class, not the instance.
- Use arrays or ArrayLists to reduce code repetition. This will make your code much easier to debug and enhance.
- Also, you can give your JTextField an ActionListener, the same as the button, and it will be triggered when enter is pressed and the text field has focus.
- If the user should only type in the days of the week and nothing else, then don't use a JTextField for this where the user can type in anything. Instead, use a JComboBox where they can only choose the Strings that you offer to them.

For example:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class GamePanel2 extends JPanel {
    public static final String[] TAG_DER_WOCH = { "Montag", "Dienstag", "Mittwoch", "Donnerstag", "Freitag", "Samstag",
            "Sonntag" };
    private JComboBox<String> tagDerWochCombo = new JComboBox<>(TAG_DER_WOCH);
    // private JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
    // private JButton knopf = new JButton("klick");

    public GamePanel2() {
        tagDerWochCombo.setSelectedIndex(-1);
        // knopf.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_K);
        
        tagDerWochCombo.addActionListener(e -> {
            System.out.println(tagDerWochCombo.getSelectedItem());
        });

        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(topPanel, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        topPanel.add(tagDerWochCombo);
        // topPanel.add(knopf);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(650, 400)));

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your patience! I sadly do not understand your proposal. Do you think that there is a way to make it more clear for me?
Do I have to create a new class with the code in your proposal?

Comment: @asgr: no, just alter your current code. The data that is under the text field and the button should be in its own JPanel, one that is placed border layout center in the main JPanel. Nest those JPanels!

Comment: I think that I kind of get your proposal but cannot think of how to include it into my code.

Comment: Also, if the user should only type in the days of the week and nothing else, then don't use a JTextField for this where the user can type in anything. Instead, use a JComboBox where they can only choose the Strings that you offer to them. As for your other questions, I have no idea what the rest of your code is doing or should look like, but I suggest that you play around with your code, experiment and see what you can come up with.

Comment: @asgr: please see edit to answer. Here is a great use of static -- for a constant String array, one that is then used to fill a JComboBox. You can then attach an ActionListener to the same box and respond to it. This prevents the user from typing in nonsense and your program from not knowing what to do with such nonsense.